# Prove that $CH$ is a height of an acute triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $\triangle ABC$ is acute. Let $D$ lie on $AB$ such that $AC^2-BC^2=BD^2-AD^2$. Show that $CD$ is an altitude.

If we suppose $CD$ is not perpendicular to $AB$, then we have $CD_1\perp AB, D_1\in AB.$ By Pythagorean theorem we can get $AC^2=AD_1^2+CD_1^2$ and $BC^2=BD_1^2+CD_1^2$. Therefore, $AC^2-BC^2=AD_1^2-BD_1^2=BD^2-AD^2$. How to approach the problem further?

Indeed, the problem statement should be $AC^2-BC^2=AD^2-BD^2$. See the comments for more thoughts about this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The given should be $AC^2-BC^2=AD^2-BD^2$

Comment: The given is fine. I think.

Comment: triangle ABC with A=90 and B=D. CD is no altitude

Comment: @Quanto, sorry, I know what you meant now.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova  The given statement is incorrect.  Please check it.  Like Quanto said, it should be $AC^2-BC^2=AD^2-BD^2$.

Comment: I wrote the statement exactly as it is written in my book.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova and it is wrong

Comment: Some words to explain me why will be fine. :)

Comment: Quanto already gave a counterexample.

Comment: @Aqua Even do not know what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: Don't find it necessary to answer. But, yes, I do have a mobile phone. Why asking

Comment: Yes, I can. It is in a different language though. https://imgur.com/oSocSqs

Comment: Added picture..

Comment: Done.............................

Comment: In the counterexample of Quanto $\angle A=90^\circ$ if I understand correctly. We have $\triangle ABC$ is acute.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova  That doesn't matter.  If you deform $\angle A$ just by a little bit (say, make it $89^\circ$), $D$ would move a little bit away from $B$, which means $CD$ won't be an altitude.

Comment: I do not get this. If $\measuredangle A=89^\circ$ why $CD$ won't be an altitude?

Comment: It ("deform $\angle A$") means that you move $A$ a little bit from the configuration in Quanto's comment.  And multiple people have tried to inform you that the problem is incorrect.  You are not listening to them.

Comment: Yes, I am listening to them. I am just trying to understand why the problem is incorrect.

Comment: The configuration in Quanto's comment is a right triangle with $\measuredangle A=90^\circ$. So we move $A$ a little bit from the configuration and what does happen?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova  Let's not bother Michael.  Suppose $D=(x,0)$.  Then, we have $AC^2=25$ and $BC^2=41$, so $AC^2-BC^2=-16$.  However, $BD^2-AD^2=(8-x)^2-x^2$.  Solve $(8-x)^2-x^2=-16$ to get $x=5$.  This will be my last reply.  I am exhausted trying to explain to you that your problem is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I got it! I was not trying to argue with you and the others. I was trying to understand what was wrong with the problem.

Comment: You got a counterexample but yet refuse to fix the problem statement.

Comment: No, you should have still edited.  You could acknowledge that the original problem was wrong, and what the correct problem should be by stating both the wrong problem and the correct problem.  And thank you for having done it.  I retracted my close vote because you edited the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $$BC^2-AC^2=BD^2-AD^2.$$

Now, by the Pythagorean theorem we obtain: 
$$BC^2-AC^2=BD_1^2-AD_1^2,$$ which gives $$BD^2-AD^2=BD_1^2-AD_1^2$$ or
$$(BD+AD)(BD-AD)=(BD_1+AD_1)(BD_1-AD_1)$$ or
$$AB(BD-AD)=AB(BD_1-AD_1)$$

$$BD-AD=BD_1-AD_1$$ or
$$BD-BD_1=AD-AD_1,$$
which gives $$D\equiv D_1.$$

Indeed, let $D_1$ is placed between $D$ and $B$ (the case $D_1$ is placed between $A$ and $D$ is the same).

Thus, $D$ is placed between $A$ and $D_1$ and 
$$BD-BD_1=AD-AD_1$$ gives $$DD_1=-DD_1,$$ which gives $$DD_1=0.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107542/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-rozenberg-prove-that-ch-is-a-height-of-an-acut).

Answer (score 2):

Apply the cosine rule to the triangles ADC and BDC

$$AC^2= AD^2 + DC^2-2AD\cdot DC\cos\angle ADC\tag1$$
$$BC^2= BD^2 + DC^2-2BD\cdot DC\cos\angle BDC\tag2$$

Note $\cos\angle ADC = -\cos\angle BDC$. Take (2)-(1) and assume the given $AC^2-BC^2=AD^2- BD^2 $to arrive at

$$AB\cdot CD \cos\angle ADC =0$$

which leads to $\angle ADC = 90$, hence $CD$ being the altitude.

Comment: Thank you for the response! We have not studied the cosine rule so I cannot understand your solution. :) +1 from me though

Comment: This is correct and Michael Rozenberg's is wrong.